# Ошибка с классом подключения к БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, ооп

Stackoverflow!
В данный момент изучаю ООП в PHP и пытаюсь создать класс, который будет автоматически подключаться к БД mysql
Получилось вот так

```
<?php 
class DataBase
{
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $password = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->showDataBaseConnect();
    }

    private function showDataBaseConnect()
    {
        $connect = $this->dataBaseConnect();
        if ($connect){
            return print 'Подключение выполнено!';
        }
        else{
            return print 'Ошибка подключения';
        }
    }

    private function dataBaseConnect()
    {
        return mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
    }
}

$connect = new DataBase();
?>
```

Пишет, что подключение удачно, даже если изменить $user на неверный. Подскажите как почему так происходит и как правильно отловить ошибку при подключении к БД
Спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Я сейчас дам ответ, но что Вы творите с безопасностью? Это же АДЪ:     private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $password = '';

Comment: @u_mulder я знаю про PDO, но хотелось бы закрепить полученные знания на практике

Comment: При чем тут PDO? Ссылку потрудились открыть и прочитать?

Comment: @u_mulder извиняюсь, подумал что это PDO

Comment: @Дмитрий боюсь спросить, а что не так? я про `private`

Comment: @Дмитрий а с чего вы взяли что `user` такой не существует? попробуйте с другими, по идеи должен выбивать ошибку, если пользователя не существует. P.S. поэтому советую в вашем случае делать так: `return @mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);`

Comment: @Manitikyl, пробовал и Вашим способом и способом, который предложил u_mulder, но выдаёт тоже самое. Если поменять пользователя с верного Root на неверный Dima, пишет, что подключение установлено.
private я использую для инкапсуляции данных подключения к БД. В дальнейшей практике буду расширять данный класс и использовать его для отправки запросов к БД

Comment: @Дмитрий я фиг его знает что у вас там, я взял ваш пример и затестил у себя, у меня все работает как надо. Указываешь неверного - пишет ошибку. Видимо ошибка у вас в чем-то другом

Comment: @Manitikyl, видимо ошибка в настройках mysql, спасибо за Ваши ответы

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот мой вариант метода

```
private function dataBaseConnect()
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password);
    if(!$conn)
       {
       $this->error = "Ошибка подключения: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       }
    return $conn;
}
```

Возвращать этот метод должен всё-таки указатель на подключение. Ну и добавьте свойство error - он получит текст ошибки, выведете его куда Вам надо.

Comment: А в чем отличие от варианта в ответе?